# Remove pagination from content

Tags: html, web-browser

Is there a plugin or tool that will remove the pagination from content articles? For example this article http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/nexus-6p-problems/.

I find this on many websites now, and it seems to be a growing trend. I can't be the only one that finds this practice lends a pour and frustrating UX. It's so frustrating to me that I'm willing to accept any solution, regardless of browser or OS (so basically, any browser/tool on any OS that can solve this issue is welcome). I normally use Chrome on Win 8, so plugins for Chrome or tools for Windows 8 would of course be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox extension [AutoPager Fixed](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/autopager-fixed/) will accomplish exactly what you want.

AutoPager Fixed will remove pagination from almost any site you desire.  It does this with the help of site-specific rules.

Rules are included for some popular sites.  For other sites, you have to create the rules yourself.

Learning how to create the rules does take a bit of effort, but once you do, you know how to create rules for almost any site.

Here is a screenshot from Mozilla showing a site with the pagination removed:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the example.

Comment: You need to create a rule within the extension to make it work.  For me, the DigitalTrends website is not working in general, so perhaps they are undergoing server maintenance.  Perhaps try creating AutoPager Fixed rules for other sites to get the hang of it.